# SSIS Package Parameter to Script Task List<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm working on a SSIS package which contains a script task. In this task I have a list of key value pairs which are hard coded string objects. What I would like to do is have a project parameter which is a list of strings which can then be passed to the script task through means of a read only variable and then parsed into a list of KeyValuePairs. Is this possible as I am unable to find material relating specifically to what I want.

Comment: This sounds a lot like data loaded from a file (hint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "list" or "array" type variable in SSIS.  You can do one of two things:

1. Make a delimited string variable and split it in your script task.
2. Make an object type variable, which is basically a datatable or resultset, and iterate through it in your script task.

Comment: I was aware of the object based approach however I can't declare object types inside of the Project parameter table as users will be required to supply data to the object when the package is deployed to a server and prior to execution. As for a delimited string, although it works I don't believe it's practical enough for the amount of data I wish to store in it. @Panagiotis suggestion is something to consider though.